# Is it possible to read JSON from a file in ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Lets say I want to deploy a Logic App using an ARM template. Here is a part of my `azuredeploy.json`:

```json
...
parameters: {
    "logic-app-definition": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The JSON definition of the logic app."
        }
    }
},
resources: [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
        "name": "lapp-my-sample",
        "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",            
        "properties": {
            "definition": "[json(parameters('logic-app-definition'))]",                
            "state": "Enabled"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the actual JSON definition of the Logic App will be taken from a string-paraemter. This is pretty uncomfortable because the template-JSON is mostly a one-line-JSON-mess mostly.

I wonder if there is a function to read the string-value from a file instead.

Comment: The tag *arm* is for the ARM microprocessor architecture, not for Azure Resource Manager. Please be more careful with the use of tags. I've have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @bmoore-msft's answer I decided to share my imprefect solution with the community.

First a simplified version of my `deploy.ps1` for brevity:

```sh
# the initial stuff like parameters and connectivity etc.

# read file content and perform regex
$ParameterFileContent = Get-Content $TemplateParametersFile
$fileName = [regex]::Matches($ParameterFileContent, "getFileJson\('(.*?)'").captures.groups[1].value
$jsonContent = (Get-Content $fileName -Raw).Replace("`n","").Replace(" ", "")
$jsonContent = [regex]::Matches($jsonContent, '{"definition":(.*)}{1}$').captures.groups[1].value
$jsonContent = $jsonContent.Replace('"', '\"')
$result = [regex]::Replace($ParameterFileContent, "[\[]getFileJson\('(.*?)'\)[\]]", $jsonContent)
Set-Content $TemplateParametersFile -Value $result
# perform deployment
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
    -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
    -Force -Verbose `
# reset the template file to the original version
Set-Content $TemplateParametersFile -Value $ParameterFileContent
```

here then is my template parameter file:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    ...
    "logic-app-definition": {
      "value": "[getFileJson('logicApp.json')]"
    }
  }
}
```

And finally here is my json template file for the logic app (`logicapp.json`):

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {},
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        { "equals": ["@outputs('HTTP')['statusCode']", 200] }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": { "HTTP": ["Succeeded"] },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": { "Accept": "application/json" },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "https://myuri/"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": { "frequency": "Hour", "interval": 6 },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

So I basically create a new magic "function" `getFileJson` and then I use RegEx before I deploy this thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to readFromUri() or anything that direct but you don't need to keep your source in a string or single-line JSON file.  Depends a bit on your orchestration (e.g. how you deploy) you can do some manipulation there and pass in a parameter or pull from a "config store" (appConfigStore, keyVault).

Happy to explore some options if you want to...

Comment: Thx. See my answer on how I solved it. I know it's messy but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do can be done using linked templates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates#linked-template

This way you can keep the Logic App template in a separate file. You can still use parameters to deploy.

Comment: I've used linked templates but as far as I understand them they are not very conveniant to hold a multi-line-JSON because they are still templates.